# Roots of Unity in Galois Theory

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

When reading about Galois theory concerning the solution by radicals of algebraic equations, one notices the following: One considers field extensions $L/K$ by adjunction of radicals. It is also required that the field $K$ contain "sufficient many roots of unity".

What does this mean, sufficient many roots of unity ?
What roots of unity are about, what is their role ?

Since $K$ can be $Q$, I dont believe it is about complex roots of unity. But at the other hand roots of unity in $R$ are trivial. So I am not sure.
Why you need to have "sufficient many roots of unity" ?

Why not all of them but only "sufficient many", and how many is sufficient, how do we know how many is sufficient ?

Can somebody elaborate on these questions ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your question is really vague as stated, so all I can offer is a comment. Usually when one considers symbols like $\sqrt[n]{x}$, there is an ambiguity in "which $n$th root of $x$" we are talking about. Thus, if you write down an equation involving lots of symbols like $\sqrt[n]{\cdots}$ whether or not it is true may depend on which $n$th roots you pick. However, if your base field contains primitive $n$th roots of unity whenever a symbol like $\sqrt[n]{\cdots}$ appears, often this dependence on the choice of $n$th root will vanish, since for example if $K$ contains $\zeta_5$, then once you've

Comment: ...got a single $5$th root of say $2$, then you've got them all. Ie, if $\sqrt[5]{2}$ denotes a particular 5th root of 2, then the other ones are just $\zeta_5\sqrt[5]{2},\zeta_5^2\sqrt[5]{2},\zeta_5^3\sqrt[5]{2}$ and $\zeta_5^4\sqrt[5]{2}$.

Comment: So, a single primitive nth root adjoint to the base field $K$ will suffice to describe all nth roots of $x\in K.$Then, given a root of unity to adjoin to $K$, without further clarification, one must consider the general case, i.e. that root of unity is not necessarily a primitive root, and thus to describe all nth roots of $x\in K$, you will need to adjoin more roots of unity. Maybe in this sense was used the term "sufficient many roots of unity". Do you share this ? What I still dont get is the acclaimed need for complex roots of unity. In $Q(\sqrt 2)$ for example you dont need them. Right?

Comment: I'm guessing the requirement for "complex roots of unity" isn't saying that the roots of unity must not be real - since after all any real number is a complex number. I think they just want to emphasize that they are talking about roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, not just roots of unity in $\mathbb{R}$. The former of course contains the latter.